# Understanding my security log

Tags: security, logging

Can someone please explain what this entry in my security report means?

> The pc (#) tried to connect to UPD port (?) on your PC without your permission.
>
> The source ip address is your own gateway. The source ip address is your own DNS server. The source ip address is your own DHCP server. The source ip address is your own local network.

Comment: What program generated this information, and what was the port number?  This is probably innocuous.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume *UPD* is meant to be UDP ([User Datagram Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)), an alternative to TCP ([Transmission Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)). When computer programs send information to each other across the internet, they often use one of these two protocols. To allow multiple programs to communicate at once, they differentiate communications by "operating" on particular numerical [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)).

As for your particular message, it seems to simply be indicating a program residing on a computer on your network tried to communicate with another remote computer and was likely blocked (either by a firewall/security settings or someone manually refusing to allow the program to connect).